# Errno::ENOENT When trying to create a new Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I followed this step by step tutorial on how to set up ruby on rails on windows: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Now, when i try to create a project i get the following message:

```
      create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  .gitattributes
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:258:in ``': No such file or directory - git config init.defaultbranch (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:258:in `user_default_branch'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:76:in `version_control'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:134:in `public_send'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:134:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:328:in `create_root_files'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/commands/application/application_command.rb:26:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/rails:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/rails:32:in `<main>'
```

I tried to reinstall everything, but without success. No tutorial mentions this Error and i can't find the solution.
Does it have something to do with the directory of my ruby installation?

Answer (score 2):

`rails new` appears to be dependent on `git` being present by default. There were [some attempts](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38115) to remove this hard dependency in the past, but apparently, it crept up again in Rails 7, probably with [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/eb261937ac856100b4e1c8a2dbb56aab6e5d140e).

As such, to create a new Rails application with Rails 7.0, you currently need to either

- have Git installed and the git command available in your $PATH
- or you have to skip the initialization of the local Git repository by passing `--skip-git` to your `rails new` command.